# hide target url when redirecting using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem:
I have several customers with websites and e-mail-adresses. They use my providers webmail-service which is simply Roundcube.

So instead of having them all to go to

> http://server20.shittyserviceprovider.com/webmail

I want them to hit their own website URL followed by **/mail** like

> http://www.mybeautifulwebsite.com/mail

Now I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mail/?$ http://server20.shittyserviceprovider.com/webmail [P]
```

which **kind of** works but it does not load the functions and css of the mailprovider.
Is there a way I can get this done?